# Conduit weird behavior

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm new to Haskell Conduit and I'm learning how to use it. I encountered a weird behevior.

Here, we have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-10.9 script

import Conduit

main :: IO ()
main = runConduit
  $ yieldMany [1..10::Int]
 .| do
      mapC id .| (await >>= maybe (return ()) leftover)
      printC
 .| do
      leftover "Hello There!"
      printC
```

and the result is:

```
$ ./Example21.hs
"Hello There!"
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I don't understand why `1` isn't printed.

Comment: N.B.: In future questions, note the tag for Stack is [haskell-stack], and not just [stack] (which is about the data structure). I removed the tag from this question because it doesn't really involve Stack.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be careful next time:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behavior of leftovers. Leftovers cannot propagate from outside of the `.|` fusion operator. As [the Haddocks](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.0/conduit-1.3.0/Data-Conduit.html#v:.-124-) say:

> Leftover data returned from the right Conduit will be discarded.

You can use the [fusion with leftovers](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.0/conduit-1.3.0/Data-Conduit.html#g:14) functions if you need to recover the leftovers.